# R indexing string with character blocks denoting nucleotide variants

Tags: regex, r, string, bioinformatics

My problem is I need to find a position in a string where I have blocks of characters which should really only be a single character position. I am working with nucleotide sequences where I need to keep track of positions within the sequence, but I have some positions where there are variants which have been denoted as [A/T] where either an A or T could be present depending on which sequence I care about (this is two similar DNA sequences which vary at a couple positions throughout the sequence). So for every one of these variant sites, the length of the sequence is an extra four characters/positions longer.

I know I could get around this by making a new code where [A/T] can be converted to, say X and [T/A] is represented by Y, but this will get confusing because there is already a standard degeneracy code, but it won't keep track of which nucleotide is from which strain (for me the one before the / is from strain A and the one after the / is from strain B). I want to index this DNA sequence string somehow, I was thinking like this below:

If I have a string like:

```
dna <- "ATC[A/T]G[G/C]ATTACAATCG"
```

I would like to get a table/data.frame:

```
pos nuc
1   A
2   T
3   C
4   [A/T]
5   G
6   [G/C]
... and so on
```

I feel like I could use strplit somehow if I knew regex better. Can I insert a condition to split at every character unless bound by square brackets which  should be kept as a block?

Comment: So after writing this I think I have a different solution, just maybe not very elegant. I make two strings, one for each possible sequence, so for my example I'd get ATCAGG... and ATCTGC... then I can just compare position by position between the two sequences as I need to. It may be a little unwieldy as these are over 2M characters long.

Comment: Why not use a regex to create an array and be done with it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library('stringr')
df <- as.data.frame(strsplit(gsub("\\[./.\\]", '_', dna), ''), stringsAsFactors=F)
df[,1][df[,1] == '_'] <- str_extract_all(dna, "\\[./.\\]")[[1]];names(df) <- 'nuc'
df
#      nuc
# 1      A
# 2      T
# 3      C
# 4  [A/T]
# 5      G
# 6  [G/C]
# 7      A
# 8      T
# 9      T
# 10     A
# 11     C
# 12     A
# 13     A
# 14     T
# 15     C
# 16     G
```

Comment: Thank you for your regex wizardry! This seems to do exactly what I need after I got the stringr library.

Comment: @GregS you mentioned that you dont want to use replacement as X !!

Comment: This solution keeps all the information from my initial sequence clear, I can infer which sequence has which nucleotide present at each variant site easily by eye. Using new single letter codes for each [n/n] variant would be very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the type of person that likes to keep things simple, here's a short trick `...`

```
x <- 'ATC[A/T]G[G/C]ATTACAATCG'
data.frame(nuc = regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\[[^]]*]|.', x))[[1]])

#      nuc
# 1      A
# 2      T
# 3      C
# 4  [A/T]
# 5      G
# 6  [G/C]
# 7      A
# 8      T
# 9      T
# 10     A
# 11     C
# 12     A
# 13     A
# 14     T
# 15     C
# 16     G
```

The above regular expression uses alternation, on the left-hand side we match the substrings that are inside square brackets, on the right-hand side we use `.` which matches any single character.

Comment: Something seems computationally intensive with this when I apply it to my 2 million character sequence.

Comment: If that is the case you could do `\\[[^]]*]|[ATCG]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another

```
dna <- "ATC[A/T]G[G/C]ATTACAATCG"

(tmp <- gsub('(\\w)(\\w)','~\\1~\\2~', dna))
# [1] "~A~T~C[A/T]G[G/C]~A~T~~T~A~~C~A~~A~T~~C~G~"

(nuc <- Filter(nzchar, strsplit(gsub("(\\[.+?\\])","~\\1~", tmp), '~')[[1]]))
# [1] "A"     "T"     "C"     "[A/T]" "G"     "[G/C]" "A"     "T"     "T"    
# [10] "A"     "C"     "A"     "A"     "T"     "C"     "G"

data.frame(nuc)
#      nuc
# 1      A
# 2      T
# 3      C
# 4  [A/T]
# 5      G
# 6  [G/C]
# 7      A
# 8      T
# 9      T
# 10     A
# 11     C
# 12     A
# 13     A
# 14     T
# 15     C
# 16     G
```

Answer (score 1):

So an easy way to get everything aside from the bracketed characters:

```
strsplit(dna, '\\[[A-Z]/[A-Z]\\]')

[[1]]
[1] "ATC"        "G"          "ATTACAATCG"
```

Perhaps negating that would give you anything inside brackets, or use the regex in the argument I listed.

EDIT:
Here is code that will get you what is in between brackets:

```
lbracket <- as.numeric(unlist(gregexpr('\\[', dna)))
rbracket <- as.numeric(unlist(gregexpr('\\]', dna)))
mapply(function(x, y) substr(dna, start=x, stop=y), lbracket, rbracket)

[1] "[A/T]" "[G/C]"
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you! This helps, I just need to keep the bracket blocks in order with all the other character blocks, which could be easy if they always alternate, but sometimes there are two or more bracket variant sites in a row [n/n][n/n].